# GitLab CI run Job only refs AND changes

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, yaml

I want to run Job only for `merge_requests` refs AND when changes for specified files, [according to official doc](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/) i create this Job in .gitlab-ci.yml:

```yaml
merge-request-test:
  <<: *some_anchor
  only:
    refs:
      - merge_requests
    changes:
      - "*.py"
      - "**/*.py"
      - postman/some-file.json
```

But this job starts even if i change any other file.

I understand that GitLab CI apply `OR` rule for `refs` and `changes` sections:

> In the example below, the test job will not be created when **any** of the
>   following are true:
>
> The pipeline runs for the master. There are changes to the README.md
>   file in the root directory of the repo.
>
> ```yaml
> test:   
>     script: npm run test
>     except:
>       refs:
>         - master
>       changes:
>         - "README.md"
> ```

I want to start this Job only for MR **and** when changes specified files. 
How i can achieve this behaviour?

If remove `refs` section, it works only when files changed, but official doc does not recommend do this, because i want to use it in pipelines:

> If using only:changes with only allow merge requests to be merged if
>   the pipeline succeeds, undesired behavior could result if you do not
>   also use only:merge_requests.

Comment: Did you check `rules` [keyword](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#ruleschanges) ?

Comment: @NicolasPepinster CI Lint says, that i can not use `rules` keyword with `only` keyword and with `when` keyword.

Comment: yes you are right. I see an [issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/28632) open  where the behavior seems similar to you question.

Comment: Docs clearly states: `With only, individual keys are logically joined by an AND`  not OR. Can you give an example of file you changed that didn't match defined globs? Seems like your configuration is fine.

Comment: @makozaki i changed README.md and Job was started

Comment: You posted your yaml and quoted yaml example from docs, are you sure you didn't push example pipeline configuration with `changes:
        - "README.md"  ` ?

Comment: @makozaki i'm sure. i tested twice. okay, i ll try to test again, but i quoted GitLab official doc, where they wrote word `any`.

Comment: Yes but this example is regarding `except` which `except is implemented as a negation of this complete expression ... This means the keys are treated as if joined by an OR.` `Except OR -> Any`, `Only AND -> All`

Comment: @makozaki yes, you are right. but in practice it does not work, even if i change README.md - Job created and started anyway, if it is MR. I created other solution and mark it as an answer. Do you test how `only` keyword works in practice?

Comment: I just checked it and job was created with only changes set to file I didn't change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now i have this working solution:

```
merge-request-deploy:
  <<: *deploy-app
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME =~ /^feature/ && $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "develop"'
      changes:
      - "*.py"
      - "**/*.py"
      - postman/some-file.json
      when: always
```

- `if: '$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME =~ /^feature/ && $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "develop"'` - gives me MR branc
- `changes` - gives me changed files

Rule's sections works with AND rule.